# Getting some Javascript remoting errors specifically in a managed package

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting

Apex:

```
global with sharing class SomeClass {
  @RemoteAction
  @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
  global static Id someMethod() {
    return u.Id;
  }
}
```

VF:

```
<apex:page controller="SomeClass">
...
<script>
...
  Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(namespace + 'SomeClass.someMethod', () => console.log("success"))
</script>
</apex:page>
```

This is the essence of what I'm trying to accomplish in my code, but I'm getting the following warning and error respectively:

`Controller not found for 'namespace__SomeClass'`

`Unable to invoke action 'namespace__SomeClass.someMethod': no controller and/or function found`

This works in my unmanaged package but does not work in my managed package. Does anyone know what might be going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.namespace.SomeClass.someMethod}'` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: `namespace + 'SomeClass.someMethod'` resolved to `namespace__SomeClass.someMethod`, instead i need to input `namespace.SomeClass.someMethod`